# Duplicated Nodes in TreeView [JavaFX]

Tags: java, treeview, javafx, duplicates

As you can see in the screenshot I've discovered a bug in the TreeView of JavaFX, i think. The TreeItems you see appear twice in the view but they don't exist twice in the "Data-Model", i've checked this.
Has anyone any idea where to look for the bug.
Here's some code from TreeItems i want to visualize in the Tree-View.
Hope it helps.

```
protected void addACompositum(Compositum newCompositum){

    newCompositum.setParent(this);
    childs.put(newCompositum.toString(), newCompositum);

    super.getChildren().add(newCompositum);
    super.setExpanded(false);
```

This is the implemented part of the Class below in which i connect the Children to it's parent.

```
abstract class AbstrCompositum extends TreeItem{

protected Compositum parent = null;

AbstrCompositum(String tag){
    super(tag.replace("\n",""));
}
```

And here i connect the data-model to my tree

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Import Resource File");
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mStage);
    if(file != null){
        Factory.getInstance().readFile(file.getPath());
        locationTreeView.setRoot(Factory.getInstance().getDataModel());
    }
```

And here you can see the double appearing Objects in the tree-view.
I've fixed a minor bug but the tree view still shows a mirrowed version of the Data Model, so the data model is two times available in the view and if i click on one both open.
Anyone a hint where to find the bug ?

[image: Mirrowed Data Model]

Comment: "*they don't exist twice in the "Data-Model", i've checked this*" => have you checked by inspecting the tree at runtime with a debugger?

Comment: The tree view's source is 100% based on the data model which i've checked at runtime, yes. but, how can i inspect the treeItems via debugger ?

Comment: Depends on your IDE but you should be able to place a breakpoint after the tree has been populated and inspect it visually.

Comment: check there was a mstk. in the source but still get this "double issue".

Comment: Are you using a custom cell factory for the TreeView?

Comment: nope, i don't use a custom cell factory.

Comment: @schwenk The best thing would be to create a minimal but complete example that reproduces your issue. I use the TreeView in a production system and have never come across that sort of issue so the problem is most likely in your code.